# Error 1267 Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query

```
SELECT * FROM leads WHERE LCASE(address) = "2560 Cherry cir"
```

I am getting the error

```
General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

I think there are some strange space characters causing the error ( 2560â€‰Cherryâ€‰cir )

The address is inputted by the user, and submitted to a php page that uses PDO to assemble and run the query.

```
<input type='text' name='address' />

$this->db->select(
            "SELECT
                *
            FROM leads
            WHERE
                LCASE(address)=:address

                array( ":address" => strtolower($address) ) );
```

The select function is defined as follows:

```
public function select($sql, $array = array(), $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {
        $sth = $this->handleDB->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $sth->bindValue("$key", $value);
        }

        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll($fetchMode);
    }
```

How should I go about addressing this issue? The collation on the database and the tables are both UTF-8? I am using PHP with PDO, and have set the charset to UTF-8 in PDO as well.

Comment: How is the address inputted by the user? Please show the HTML and PHP code also.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Updated my question

Comment: Do you also use the meta tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">`  within your HTML? And connected with PDO with UTF-8 charset?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, I have both <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset="UTF-8"> and am creating a PDO instance with  new PDO($DB_TYPE.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME.";charset=utf8", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS,
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

Comment: It seems to happen when some strange character is pasted in

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the table was set to the UTF-8 collation, but the column was set to Latin.